# How to get SSDT address

Tags: c, winapi, windbg, windows-kernel

I'm trying to write a program in c that lists the SSDT addresses so if some function is hooked I would see a different address.
How do I get the address of SSDT?
I used WinDbg and listed with KeServiceDescriptorTable, now how I get this address in c.
I searched the web for it and saw programs that used NtQuerySystemInformation with SystemModuleInformation. I didn't find any documentation for those programs or any articles or explanations for this.

Thanks for helping

Comment: Ordinary programs run in user-mode.  To look at the system descriptor table, you'll need your code to run in kernel-mode, i.e. as a driver: https://github.com/proteansec/visual-studio-projects/tree/master/hookssdt.  Or maybe not; see next comment.

Comment: Undocumented NtQuerySystemInformation Structures: https://gist.github.com/jNizM/ddf02494cd78e743eed776ce6164758f
Similar: http://www.exploit-monday.com/2013/06/undocumented-ntquerysysteminformation.html

Comment: @asynchronos I didnt understand you... Can I look at the SSDT from user-mode?

Comment: Not without help from kernel-mode.  I thought maybe an undocumented information class for NtQuerySystemInformation() might read it for you, but I haven't found any such thing class/structure.

Answer (score 0):

[Below is for when you're in kernel-mode].

On 32-bit environments, KeServiceDescriptorTable is exported by NTOSKRNL, and thus you can retrieve the address with [MmGetSystemRoutineAddress](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/wdm/nf-wdm-mmgetsystemroutineaddress).

On 64-bit environments however, you'll need to locate KeServiceDescriptorTable yourself through memory scanning because it won't be exported by NTOSKRNL. It is quite straight forward once you've found out where it the table is used in the Windows Kernel, check the internal system-call related routines in NTOSKRNL.

Note: you'll need to byte-shift when extracting the address on a 64-bit environment.

Now, once you have the addresses, you can do a comparison to determine if the addresses are between a specific range in memory to try and determine whether the address is not correct (e.g. if it has been manipulated). You can also perform forensics on the operands at the memory for an in-depth analysis.